# Is it possible to integrate modern React.js components into ES5 AngularJs app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

We have an old style application, written in AngularJs and we would like to "import" couple of editors written in ReactJs.

First idea was [ngReact](https://github.com/ngReact/ngReact), which is also old school (and available on bower :)) but I was not able to reference neither React or our react components.

As those two things are actually not written in same standard, is it even possible to mix them?
Or is there option to downgrade React components to ES5 during the compile & build?

Why don't we modernize angular app?

We are waiting for completely new ReactJs application version and in a meanwhile we are still using our old one. While we are waiting for the new one, we just wanted to grasp some new features in the old gui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up with rewriting angularjs to the ES6 and now they work together well.

It took couple of days, but I can say that I am more happy now than that we had that odd mixture we initially wanted to have.